# Signal enhancing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-series, signal-processing, data-analysis

I need an algorithm (preferable in a Pascal-like language, but it the end doesn't really matter) that will make the "signal" (actually a series of data points) in left look like the one in right.
[image: signal enhancing]

Signal origin:
The signal is generated by a machine. Oversimplifying the explanation, the machine is measuring the density of a liquid flowing through a transparent tube. So, the signal is nothing similar to an electrical signal (audio/radio frequency).
The data points could look like this: [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 13, 14, 15, 18, 23, 19, 17, 15, 15, 15, 14, 11, 9, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]

What I need:
I need to accurately detect the 'peaks'. For this, I already have a piece of code but it is not working on poor signals as the one shown in the image below.
I think we can see this, as a signal that was accidentally passed through a low-pass filter, and now I want to restore it.

Notes:
There are 4 signals, but they are separated so they can be analyzed individually. So, it is enough to think about how to process just one of them.

After a peak, if the signal is not coming down fast enough we can consider that there are multiple peaks (you can best see that in the 'red' signal at the end of the series).
[image]

The advantage is that the whole series is available (so the signal is not in real time, it is already stored on file)!

**[Edit by Spektre] I extracted Red sample points from the image**

```cpp
float f0[]={ 73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,71,69,68,66,64,62,58,54,49,41,33,25,17,13,15,21,30,39,47,54,59,62,64,66,67,68,69,70,71,71,72,72,72,71,71,70,69,68,67,66,65,63,62,60,56,51,45,37,29,22,18,18,22,28,33,35,36,35,32,26,20,15,12,15,20,26,31,35,37,36,34,30,25,22,22,27,33,41,48,55,60,63,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,71,70,69,67,65,63,60,55,49,40,30,21,13, 7,10,17,27,36,45,52,56,59,60,61,62,62,62,62,61,61,59,57,53,47,40,32,24,18,15,18,23,28,32,33,31,28,23,16,10, 6, 8,13,20,27,31,32,31,28,22,15,10, 6,10,16,23,30,34,36,36,34,29,24,20,19,24,30,37,44,51,56,59,61,62,63,64,64,64,65,64,64,62,60,57,53,48,43,38,36,39,43,49,54,59,63,66,68,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73 };
float f1[]={ 55,58,60,62,64,66,67,68,68,69,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,68,67,66,64,63,61,60,59,57,55,52,49,46,43,40,37,35,34,33,32,32,33,34,36,37,39,41,43,45,47,50,52,55,57,59,60,61,61,62,62,62,62,61,61,60,58,57,55,53,51,49,48,46,44,42,40,38,35,32,30,29,28,27,27,26,26,26,25,25,24,23,23,23,24,24,25,25,26,26,26,27,28,29,31,33,35,38,40,41,43,44,46,48,50,53,55,57,59,60,61,62,63,64,64,65,65,64,63,61,59,57,54,52,50,47,45,42,39,37,34,32,31,30,30,30,31,32,34,36,37,39,40,41,42,43,44,44,44,44,43,42,41,40,38,36,34,32,30,28,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,21,23,24,25,26,26,26,27,28,29,31,34,36,37,38,40,41,43,45,47,48,49,50,51,51,51,50,49,49,48,48,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,60 };
const int n=sizeof(f0)/sizeof(f0[0]);
```

All the values need to be transformed:

```
f0[i] = 73.0-f0[i];
f1[i] = 73.0-f1[i];
```

To offset back from image... `f0` is the original Red signal and `f1` is the distorted Yellow one.

[image: plot]

This is the closest I get to with first order FIR filter:

[image: FIR filter]

The upper half is plot of used FIR filter weights (editable by mouse so the FIR is hand drawed for fast weights find...). Bellow are the signal plots:

- Red original (Ideal) signal `f0`
- Dark green measured signal `f1`
- Light Green FIR filtered Ideal signal `f2`

  The FIR filter is just convolution where zero offset element is the last and here the weight values:

```cpp
float fir[35] = { 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.0007506932, 0.003784107, 0.007575874, 0.01060929, 0.01591776, 0.02198459, 0.03032647, 0.04170178, 0.05686884, 0.06445237, 0.06900249, 0.07203591, 0.07203591, 0.0705192, 0.06900249, 0.06672744, 0.06217732, 0.05611049, 0.04928531, 0.04170178, 0.03335989, 0.02653471, 0.02046788, 0.01515941, 0.009850933, 0.005300813, 0.0007506932 };
```

So either there is also some higher degree of FIR or the weights need to be tweaked a bit more. Anyway this should be enough for the deconvolution and or fitting ... btw the FIR filter is done as follows:

```cpp
const int fir_n=35;     // size (exposure time) [samples]
const int fir_x=fir_n-1;    // zero offset element [samples]
int x,y,i,j,ii;
float a,f2[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
 for (f2[i]=0.0,ii=i-fir_x,j=0;j<fir_n;j++,ii++)
  if ((ii>=0)&&(ii<n)) f2[i]+=fir[j]*f0[ii];
```

Comment: The description is so vague ... My intuition tells me your signal got low pass filtered (unwillingly) and you want to reconstruct the original. If you know the frequency , phase and amplitude of the filtered out sin-wave  (constant or proportional to base signal) then you can just modulate the input signal with it. add some sample dataset (numbers) and more info about the signal so we can actually have something to test.

Comment: Since this is more a DSP theory question than an actual practical programming question I suggest you try asking on http://dsp.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Spektre-Thanks. I updated the question. If there are still ambiguities let me know and I will add more explanations. PS: the signal was not filtered, BUT yes, my problem is like this.

Comment: @SolarWind I have no idea what you are asking. How is the signal on the left related to the one on the right? How is the signal on the right supposed to represent a "detection of peaks" for the signal on the left?

Comment: @this-vidor-Your question could be answered by this "If the signal is staying too long up, we can consider that there are multiple peaks (you can best see that in the 'red' signal at the end of the series)". I added an extra image to explain it. Also, please note that this is NOT an audio signal.

Comment: @SolarWind Does the signal not "go down fast enough" because of mechanical properties of the sensor?

Comment: @this-vidor-Yes. The liquid is not clearing the tube fast enough... it lingers in tube.

Comment: @SolarWind So it sounds like the measured (left) signal is an accurate representation of fluid in some tube. And the target (right) signal is some kind of driving signal that controls flow into the tube? You're giving us a physics problem, and will probably get better results by (a) posting this in a different channel of Stack Exchange, and (b) actually describing the experimental setup, and the **mechanical** (causal) link between the two signals. In the same spirit as Spektre's answer, my intuition is that you can model the smoothing as a convolution, and should research 1D de-convolution.

Comment: @this-vidor-can you recommend a library that does 1D de-convolution?

Comment: See [scipy.signal.deconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html).

Comment: @SolarWind separate the notification `@nick` with space from the remaining text otherwise site will not notify the user `nick`. You wrote `@Spektre-Thanks` so site was searching for user `Spektre-Thanks` instead of `Spektre` and I was not notified at all. We need both signals example (original and measured) to obtain the filter parameters. And the signal **is low pass filtered** due to measuring. Your liquid flows in constant volume and you are measuring by integrating (most likely light) for some time. In theory the sensor exposure time should be enough if no other `inertia` is present.

Comment: @SolarWind added test data to your Question

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should start with a pretty simple **system identification** and consecutive **signal reconstruction**. Also, I would recommend to implement your algorithm first in a mathematical prototyping tool like Matlab (commerical license) or Octave (free → https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html).  These tools provide an ease of signal processing no programming language like Pascal or Java could ever offer, no matter what library you use. After you successfully designed your algorithm with Matlab or Octave, then think about how to implement it with Pascal.

Lets assume the behaviour of the tube can be characterized by a **linear time-invariant system** (e.g. a  linear lowpass filter). This is by no means guaranteed but a worthwhile approach (at least until it fails:) ). Following the same approach for non-linear and/or time-variant systems becomes pretty involved and you will need professional help to do this I would imagine.

If I understood your description correctly, you have access to both the input and output signals of the tube. If I am wrong and you don’t know the input signal, you might be able to apply some calibration signal first, whose characteristics you know, and record the output signal. Knowing input and output signals is a prerequisite for the following approach. Without both signals you can not approximate the impulse response h of the tube. After calculating an approximation of h, we can design an inverse filer called ge and eventually reconstruct the input from the output signal.

Here is the signal flow of a input signal x[n] passing your tube described by h producing the output signal y[n]. Taking y[n] and applying an inverse filtering operation described by ge we obtain xr[n]

**x[n] →|  h  | → y[n] → |  ge  | → xr[n]**

Take an input vector x of length N and a corresponding vector of y of the same length. 
Now you express the output y as a convolution of an input convolution matrix X (see the code below for its implementation) with the unknown impulse response of your system, i.e.

**y = X * h**

with the vector and matrix sizes y = N x 1, X = N x N and h = N x 1 
You can calculate a **least-squares approximation** of the impulse response he, by calculating

**he  = inv(X'*X)*X' * y**

where X' describes the transpose and inv() the matrix inverse of X. he represents a column vector of the identified impulse response of your tube which we obtained via a **1-D deconvolution**. You can check how well the identification worked by calculating the output of your estimated system,

**ye = X * he**

and by comparing ye and y.   Now, we try to reconstruct x from y and he. The reconstructed input vector xr is calculated by

**xr = Ge * y**

where Ge = inv(He) and He is the N x N convolution matrix of he. 
Here is some Octave code. Copy both functions in their own dedicated file (reconstruct.m and getConvolutionMatrix.m) and type "reconstruct.m" into the Octave command line to examine the outputs of the example. Please note the sample code works only for vector of odd length (N is odd). Play around with the size N of your vectors. This might help the approximation accuracy.

```
function [Ge] = reconstruct ()
    x = [1 2 3]';            # input signal
    # h = [1 3 2]';          # unknown impulse response
    y = [5 11 13]';          # output signal
    y = y + 0.001*randn(length(y),1)  # add noise to output signal 

    Xm = getConvolutionMatrix(x)
    Xps = inv(Xm'*Xm)*Xm';
    he = Xps * y
    He = getConvolutionMatrix(he);
    Ge = inv(He);
    # reconstructed impulse signal
    xr = Ge*y
endfunction

function [mH] = getConvolutionMatrix(h)
    h = h(:)';
    hlen = length(h);
    Nc = (hlen-1)/2;

    mH= zeros(hlen, hlen);
    hp = [zeros(1,Nc) h zeros(1,Nc)];

    for c=1:hlen
      for r=1:hlen
        mH(r,c) = hp(r+hlen-c);
      end
    end
endfunction
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "input and output signals of the tube". There is just one sensor measuring the flow through the tube. This sensor outputs a signal. So, there is no 'input' signal.

Comment: At the beginning of your problem description you mentioned, you wanted an algorithm that made the signals on the left of your diagram look like the signals on the right. The signal on the left is the sensor output signal, correct? The signal on the right side of the diagram is what you want your algorithm to generate, so this would be the input signal x in the algorithm I described. To say it in different words, you have your sensor signal, a signal you want to obtain and the tube that generates the sensor signal, you need two out of these three quantities to calculate the third.